# Adding text shadow to your whole website

Tags: css, optimization

I want to add shadow to all the text into a website. The text is in different elements of the website.

Now I was thinking of 2 things.

1) add a class to all the containers with text, and just give the class the text-shadow style. This will give me a lot of work tho, adding a class the all the elements in the website. And what will this do with the DOM?

2) Add styling to all the elements:

```
h1,h2,h3,li,p,span{text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(51, 69, 78, 0.5);}
```

Which one of the 2 is better to use, or is there a better, more optimized way to do this?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in there

Comment: Sorry, I edited this in. Hit that post button to quickly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO you should not create a specific class just for `text-shadow`. That's like adding presentation back into the document. `text-shadow` should be added to those elements (or predefined classes) that require it. So, of your two options, #2 would be my recommendation, although I would have said you should only be adding it to a subset of predefined classes. And not all elements/classes would require the same type of shadow.

Do you *really* want to add `text-shadow` to *every* bit of textual content?! Large blocks of text should not have `text-shadow` applied in my opinion. This could make the text harder to read and hence cause some accessibility issues.

Comment: I'd like to add +2 for "do you really want…"

Comment: It's not going to be a website with large chunks of texts. It's more a showcase for html5 and css3 features and designs.

Answer (score 3):

If this is going to apply to all text, you just need to start with:

```
body, input, textarea, select {
    text-shadow : 1px 1px 1px rgba(51, 69, 78, 0.5);
}
```

On testing, you might need to add one or two other elements for total coverage. For example, note that some form elements had to be included explicitly; they're annoying like that. Also remember this is not going to apply to anything that's not actually *in* the document, like iframes.

If you *really* want to cheat, you can just apply the property to the universal selector:

```
* {
    text-shadow : 1px 1px 1px rgba(51, 69, 78, 0.5);
}
```

But given some findings about that being inefficient(it gets applied to *every single thing* on the page) and the type of processing involved in creating things like shadows, it might not be a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't apply it to a bunch of elements individually; just set it at the top and the shadow will apply to all contained text.

```
body { text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(51, 69, 78, 0.5); }
```

(If it didn't work this way, then there would be lots of inconveniences from document structure, such as if you specified a shadow on a paragraph which contained a link.)